# Python2 + PyQt5: how to get value of QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like ask how to get the value of QDoubleSpinBox. It confuses me as a new user. Hier is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDoubleSpinBox

import sys

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)

        dsbox = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
        dsbox.setDecimals(1)
        dsbox.setValue(100.00)
        dsbox.setMinimum(1.00)
        dsbox.setMaximum(3500.00)
        dsbox.setSingleStep(1.00)
        dsbox.setSuffix("mm")

        dsbox.valueChanged.connect(self.on_value_changed)

        self.show()

    def on_value_changed(self):
        print "You are now in the sub function."
        print self.dsbox.value() #Problem is hier

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The result is:

```
You are now in the sub function.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It means something is wrong with this line: `print self.dsbox.value()`

I have checked that there is a "value" public function for QDoubleSpinBox Class:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html

So what have I done wrong hier? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change all `dsbox.....` to `self.dsbox....`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you! That works!